# containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion error when trying to access healthkit

Tags: swift, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I am trying to use healthKit in my application where I authenticate it by doing the following:

```
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

    let typesToShare: Set = [
        HKQuantityType.workoutType()
    ]

    let typesToRead: Set = [
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
        HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!
    ]

    healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: typesToShare, read: typesToRead) { (success, error) in
        // handle error
    }
```

The following notification appears:

[Image requesting user to open application to accept health data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPugZ.png)

but the request to access healthKit never appears on the user's device when the application opens and I receive the following error in console:

```
ChangApp WatchKit Extension[72042:4030925] [default] containerAppExtensionEntitlementsWithCompletion: failed with error: (null)
```